# Building double infinite polling behavior in RX

Tags: python, system.reactive, observable, rx-py

The problem is to emulate the double looping behavior with RX:

```
while True:
    try:
        token = get_token()
        while True:
            try:
                value = get_value_using_token(token)
                do_something(value)
            except:
                break
    except:
        break
```

It would be clean if the two loops are replaced with two observables, one acting as an observer of the outer one, while `do_something(value)` can be replaced with an observer on its own. Any exceptions can be handled nicely as well. Outer loop needs to be blocking, but inner loop may not be, as I am trying to use outer loop to handle exceptions using retry function with a backoff function.

So far I can build a sequence using:

```
Observable.from_iterable(value for value in iter(get_token, None))
    .subscribe(do_something)
```

but how can I make a similar structure in blocking mode for the outer?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `Repeat` operator to create a loop. And then you need the  `Retry` operator to continue on failure.

Something like

```
Observable.return(get_token())
    .flatMap(token->Observable.return(get_value_using_token(token))
        .repeat())
    .retry()
.subscribe(do_something)
```

*I dont know python, so I hope you can convert that psuedo code

Comment: Thanks. But repeat operator returns the same value. What I need is to repeat function invocation, as neither `get_token` nor `get_value_using_token` is a pure function.

Comment: Sorry, of course. Then you can change Observable.Return to RxPy's equivilent of `Observable.Start` or you can use `Observable.Defer(Obs.Return(GetToken()))` this will make it lazily evalualted again.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to create an infinite stream of functions using `repeat` operator, and `map` to its invocation.

```
def get_token():
    return some_value

def get_value_with_token(token):
    return some_value_using_token

Observable.repeat(get_token)\
    .map(lambda f: f())\
    .map(lambda n: O.repeat(lambda: get_value_with_token(n)))\
    .concat_all()\
    .map(lambda f: f())\
    .subscribe(logger.info)
```

where `get_token` and `get_value_with_token` are functions.

By using blocking functions for both, I can make a double loop, and apply additional `rx` operators such as `retry` to the observable.